# Conflict between jQuery Tools and Flexible Slide to top Accordion

Tags: jquery, conflict, jquery-tools

I´ve already asked this question at the comment section of the tutorial-site http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/12/flexible-slide-to-top-accordion/

I want include this "Slide-to-top-Accordion" script into the jQuery Tools Tabs http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/index.html but it looks like there is a conflict between this two scripts...

Have anyone an idea to solve this problem? I would be very grateful!

**Here is the Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/design/js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabbox-produkte">

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#" title="">asd</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" title="">asd</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">sad</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="panes">
                <div>
                    <p>Iasd</p>

                </div>
                <div id="preise">
                     <div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Photography<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                            <p>She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way.</p>

                            <p>When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane.</p>
                            <p>Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
                            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image01"/>
                            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image02"/>
                            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image03"/>
                            <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image04"/>
                            <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image05"/>
                            <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image06"/>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Web Design<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                            <p>Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                            <p>A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth.</p>

                            <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="image07"/>
                            <img src="images/8.jpg" alt="image08"/>
                            <img src="images/9.jpg" alt="image09"/>
                            <img src="images/10.jpg" alt="image10"/>
                            <img src="images/11.jpg" alt="image11"/>
                            <img src="images/12.jpg" alt="image12"/>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <a href="#">Illustrations<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                            <p>O my friend - but it is too much for my strength - I sink under the weight of the splendour of these visions!</p>
                            <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.</p>
                            <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine.</p>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Miscancellous<span class="st-arrow">Open or Close</span></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                            <p>The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me?"</p>
                            <p>He thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls.</p>
                        </div>

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/design/js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/design/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(function() {

            $j('#st-accordion').accordion({
                oneOpenedItem   : true
            });

        });

    </script> 

                </div>
                <div>

                        adsasd          
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">      
                $(function() {
                $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries, you can write:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

and use `$j` instead of `$` for jquery calls.

Comment: Ok, this looks easy but i have still problems. I´ve added the Code in my Post above. Is this the right way?

Comment: Big sorry, but I dont really understand it ... Better i´ve add the whole Code in my Post, just one sec.

Comment: Ok, the Code is now in my post. May you can find my fault?

Comment: seems it is not conflict of jquery with something. can you place simple example on http://jsfiddle.net/ use add resource to add other script exept jquery. not use noConflict;

Comment: Sorry - had the days no time ... I tried now another tabsystem and use this ones: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/tabs.html but there are still problems with this special slide to top script ... i uploaded now here http://www.xancoremedia.com/neu/ the second tab you can see the errors ... may you can now help to slove this one? would be very greatful!

Comment: Works for me, at xancoremedia.com/neu (chrome) btw, may be it would be usefull for you to use jquery-ui lib it have tabs and accordion and much more